# What do some of these AWK commands do?

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to learn the AWK command for this chapters homework, and one of the examples they gave as a command was:

```
awk -F: '{printf "%s\t %s\n", $1, $2}' datafile
```

While I understand most of these terms, im lost as to what the `"%s\t %s\n"` refer to. I cant seem to find what their purpose in this command is exactly to do. Any feedback will help as I am a 1st year linux student, that being said please try not to get too technical with a response

Answer (score 1):

The first `%s` is where the value of `$1` will be placed.

The second `%s` is where the value of `$2` will be placed.

`\t` is a tab.

`\n` is a newline.

Answer (score 0):

`awk -F:` setting field separator to `:` 
`'{printf "%s\t %s\n", $1, $2}'` print field nr1 tab field nr2 enter
 datafile

Some more detail
`"%s` #get first filed ($1)
`\t`#tab + a blank space
`%s` #get second filed ($2)
`\n` #add a new line
`"`
`, $1` #fist field
`, $2` #second field

Also see here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html

Comment: It should be ok now, I did click enter for new line and it posted it

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [man pages](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)?

`-F` is delimiter - you say that the fields you process are separated by `:`, like:

```
foo:bar:baz
1:2:3
```

`printf` is a print-with-format instruction where

- `%s` - print string
- `\t` - print tab
- `\n` print new line
- `$1`, `$2` - print first and second element (like `foo` and `bar` in `foo:bar:bas`)

`printf` consumes three arguments here: first is the format (`%s…` part, a "mold"), and next two arguments (`$1` and `$2`) are the variables that you want to display with the format (you cram them into the mold). First variable (here - `$1`) will replace first `%s` and the second one (`$2`) will replace second `%s`.

Comment: Thank you, i wish these books went a little more in depth!

Comment: and yes i did man awk and honestly since im so new..i didnt know awk and gawk were the same so i exited... -.-